# JTable and JComboBox - save JTable on text file and load values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a `JTable` with only one column, this column has `JComboBox` items in it.
I found a way to save all values from my `JTable` to a txt file.

I have also found a way to load values from a txt file, here is the code:

```
private JTable table = createMyTable ();
private void loadTable(File file) {
String line;
BufferedReader reader;
String ColumnName = "ComboBox values";
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int i = 0;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
               JComboBox comboBox = createComboBox();
               tabel.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(
                                            new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

               String string_Col = line.trim();

                 if ( !index.isEmpty() ) 
                   comboBox.setSelectedIndex(index);
               i++;
        }
        reader.close();
}

private JComboBox createComboBox () {
   int array [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
   JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
   for (int value : array)
     comboBox.addItem(value);
      return comboBox;

}
```

The text file is a simple file with numbers for each line, like this:

```
34
23
2
43
12
```

I want to restore those values and put them in `JComboBox` rows in my `JTable`.

The problem is that my solution is not so good to restore those values, because the `JComboBox` values are just written into the `JTable` cells, so when I click on a row the relative `JComboBox` component immediately focuses and selects the first item of the list and the value that I previously restored is lost. I don't understand this behaviour.

So is there a good way to get those files from the file and put them in `JComboBox` components of the `JTable` in a correct way, in order to guarantee the normal `JComboBox` behaviour that is that, when I click on a `JComboBox` component, the focus has to remain on the previously selected index?

Thanks

**edit:**

I edited my code, `loadTable()` is the function I use to get `JComboBox` values from txt file and I use `combo.setSelectedIndex(index);` to do what I need, but it does not work and it seems not to work because the `JComboBox` is put insede the `JTable` using `tabel.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));` so maybe there is something wrong with that.

Indeed, I tried to add some debugging code at the end of my `loadTable()` function, I just tried to add the `JComboBox` out from `JTable`, and guess what? It works, the `JComboBox` now shows the selected item to the right index. Instead it does not when it is inside the `JTable`.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem. And the values should be hardcoded in the program because we don't have access to your text file.

Comment: how you create your table?